# Android: Keep notifications open on button press

Tags: android, notifications

I have a `NotificationCompat.Builder` which has a custom `RemoteView` set via its `setContent` method. This `RemoteView` contains, among other things, a couple of buttons.

I attach a `PendingIntent` to the button via
`notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_button_plusone, pIntentPlusOne);`

The problem is that I don't want the Notification Drawer to dissapear after a button is pressed, but keep it open, so that I can press the `R.id.notification_button_plusone`-Button multiple times without needing to pull down the Notification Drawer for each button press.

Also, I might want to press the +1 button (unrelated to Google Plus, just to add weight to something) multiple times, then press a star-button and finally a share button in the same notification. The button press on the share button should close the notification drawer, all other buttons should keep it open.

How can I do that? I see that the App "Power Toggles" is able to do that, that's the behaviour I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `PendingIntent` is created via a call to `PendingIntent.getService(...)` instead of `PendingIntent.getActivity(...)`, then the Notification Drawer won't close.

If desired, it is then possible to close the Notification Drawer in the Service via a call to `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS))`

Answer (score 1):

Actions in *expanded* notifications (Jellybean and above) support this. If you attach a pending intent to such an action, and the pending intent is not to an activity, the drawer should remain open (it definitely does for a broadcast pending intent, I think also for a service pending intent). Lots of apps use this for quick toggling etc.

I am not sure  if it's possible to achieve the same thing from a RemoteViews custom layout in a non expanded notification, if that's what you're currently using, but I would suspect that if your notification does not have autoCancel and your buttons don't launch activities, it should work? You might want to post more of your code if this isn't the case.

I am not familiar with power toggles, but from its screenshots it looks like it might be using remoteviews rather than actions.